# Rails 4 use link_to or button_to to run method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing a simple voting system and by clicking on a button a +1 is added. For example, if a question has 5 votes, it will just increase. I have written the method already, but I am not sure how to execute it by clicking on a link_to. Do I need to reconfigure my routes?

**questions_controller.rb**

```
  def self.ping
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.increment!(:amplify)

    render_to do |format|
      if @question.save
        format.html { redirect_to @question }
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :questions
post '/ping' => 'questions#ping', as: 'ping'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your routes will need to support an `id`:

`post '/ping/:id' => 'questions#ping', as: 'ping'`

Or better yet, if you want it to be scoped within the question:

```
resources :questions do
  post '/ping' => 'questions#ping', as: ping
end
```

However, I don't think you want a class method `ping` in your questions_controller.  I think you just want an instance method:

```
def ping
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  @question.increment!(:amplify)

  if @question.save
    render_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @question }
    end
  end
end
```

If that doesn't work, what errors do you see in the logs?

Comment: I should have posted my view: `<%= link_to question.amplify, question.ping %>`

`question` is already defined and the ping method is called, however nothing happens at all.


It also works fine, if I add `<% question.increment!(:amplify) %>` into my view.

Comment: @user3048402 Try `<%= link_to question.amplify, ping_path(question) %>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Further to CDub's answer, you'll likely benefit from a [member route (2.10)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

---

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :questions do
   member do 
       post :ping
   end
end
```

This should provide these routes:

```
http://yourapp.com/questions/:question_id/ping
```

---

**View**

This URL will only be accessible from `POST`, and would be best accessed using a `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "+1", question_ping_path(question.id), method: :post %>
```

---

**Controller**

You don't need to declare class methods in a controller

#app/controllers/questions_controller.rb
 def ping
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @question.increment!(:amplify)

```
render_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @question }
end
```

end

[**.increment!**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) saves the record :)